# Why can't I access my website with domain? It works with IP address only

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

In the past we didn't have a proper domain name for our site, now I have registered a proper domain name, but now I experiance the following problem:

1. If I go to `https://46.144.46.214/ita` I can access the portal without any problem;
2. If I go to https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ita I receive a time-out in Internet Explorer.
3. But if I go to https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ I see that I reach the IIS server so the DNS is working.

Do you know how it is possible that I can reach it by IP and not by name? I need to reach it by domain. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a Redirect loop.

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA
--2012-09-04 23:33:44--  https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA
Resolving ita.telvent-netherlands.com (ita.telvent-netherlands.com)... 46.144.46.214
Connecting to ita.telvent-netherlands.com (ita.telvent-netherlands.com)|46.144.46.214|:443... connected.

WARNING: The certificate of `ita.telvent-netherlands.com' is not trusted.
WARNING: The certificate of `ita.telvent-netherlands.com' hasn't got a known issuer.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA/ [following]

--2012-09-04 23:33:46--  https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA/
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /ITA/Login.aspx?action=timeout [following]

--2012-09-04 23:33:46--  https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA/Login.aspx?action=timeout
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /ITA/Login.aspx?action=timeout [following]

--2012-09-04 23:33:46--  https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA/Login.aspx?action=timeout
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /ITA/Login.aspx?action=timeout [following]

...

Continues until web browser gives up...
```

https://ita.telvent-netherlands.com/ITA/Login.aspx?action=timeout appears to be redirecting to itself in an endless loop.

Comment: how can I fix the "redirecting to itself" issue? Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Dig into your code - that is where the problem is.